# Read out embedded Facedetection data from USB camera

Tags: image-processing, camera, metadata

i bought an industrial usb 3.0 camera which has an built in facedetection. According to the Manual, the roi can be embededded in the pixel data. My biggest challenge is to understand the manual on how the data is stored in the pixel data. ( Getting an image, reading out single pixels is not an problem)

Maybe someone can give me a hint on how it works.

I attached some screenshots if the manual.

Thank you very much

[image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G087v.png)

[cut out embedded data from example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bZYs.jpg)

[Part 1 Manual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoXj1.jpg)

[Part 2 Manual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzO8i.jpg)

Comment: What is the name of this camera?  Can you make a sample image available?

Comment: SeeCam_CU135

added Sample above

Comment: Sorry I can't be more helpful.  I was hoping at the very least to be able to bring this up in the exiftool forum, but since the data is embedded in the image itself rather than using pre-existing region metadata specs, exiftool won't be able to extract this as it never touches image data.